# EF5 Code First Fluent EntityTypeConfiguration for tracks & albums models

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am modeling music tracks and albums where Albums have many tracks and Tracks can be on only one album, with a join table to specify it's position in the album listing.

Here are my models:

```
public class Track
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int AlbumTrackId { get; set; }
    public virtual AlbumTrack AlbumTrack { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AlbumTrack> AlbumTracks { get; set; }
}

public class AlbumTrack
{
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }

    public int TrackId { get; set; }
    public virtual Track Track { get; set; }

    public int Position { get; set; }
}
```

and my EntityTypeConfiguration

```
public class AlbumTrackConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<AlbumTrack>
{

    public AlbumTrackConfiguration()
    {
        // AlbumTrack has a composite key
        HasKey(at => new {at.AlbumId, at.TrackId});

        // AlbumTrack has one Album, Albums have many AlbumTracks
        HasRequired(at => at.Album)
            .WithMany(a => a.AlbumTracks)
            .HasForeignKey(at => at.AlbumId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        // AlbumTrack has one Track, Tracks have one AlbumTrack
        HasRequired(at => at.Track)
            .WithRequiredPrincipal(t=>t.AlbumTrack)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }

}
```

The one to many relationship between Albums and AlbumTracks is fine, but in addition to the expected

```
[AlbumTrackId] [int] NOT NULL,
```

Code First keeps adding

```
[AlbumTrack_AlbumId] [int] NOT NULL,
[AlbumTrack_TrackId] [int] NOT NULL
```

to the Tracks table.

How can I model the Track to Album Track relationship better so that only the properties I specify translate in db fields?

[Yes, in my world a track can only exist on a single album!]

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making a position part of the `Track` makes sense as suggested.
But if you'd still want your 'join' table to work - and I'd personally always rather disassociate the track, albums from their 'associations', i.e. positions etc...

For that to work you need to re-organize your relationships just a bit. EF/CF is failing to build that - because you're asking of it something that isn't natively supported or expected. Join, index tables are always expecting 'multiplicity' on the other side.

> Basically, your `AlbumTrack` is no longer a 'join' table - but is just
>   a `one-on-one` with the `Track` + you have the `Album` fk from the
>   AlbumTrack.

With that in mind you can do the following - and that'd create columns, indexes just right...

```
public class Track
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    // public int AlbumTrackId { get; set; }
    public virtual AlbumTrack AlbumTrack { get; set; }
}
public class AlbumTrack
{
    public int TrackId { get; set; } // <== this is a single primary
    public virtual Track Track { get; set; }

    public int AlbumId { get; set; }
    public virtual Album Album { get; set; }

    public int Position { get; set; }
}
public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AlbumTrack> AlbumTracks { get; set; }
}
```

...and with the fluent configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AlbumTrack>()
    .HasKey(at => new { at.TrackId });
    //.HasKey(at => new { at.AlbumId, at.TrackId });

modelBuilder.Entity<AlbumTrack>()
            .HasRequired(at => at.Track)
            .WithOptional(a => a.AlbumTrack);
            // .WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.AlbumTrack);

modelBuilder.Entity<AlbumTrack>()
    .HasRequired(at => at.Album)
    .WithMany(a => a.AlbumTracks)
    .HasForeignKey(at => at.AlbumId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

...and you can use it like:

```
var album1 = db.Albums.Add(new Album { Name = "Track1", });

var tr1 = db.Tracks.Add(new Track { Name = "Track1", });
var tr2 = db.Tracks.Add(new Track { Name = "Track2", });
var tr3 = db.Tracks.Add(new Track { Name = "Track3", });
var tr4 = db.Tracks.Add(new Track { Name = "Track4", });
var tr5 = db.Tracks.Add(new Track { Name = "Track5", });

db.AlbumTracks.Add(new AlbumTrack { Track = tr1, Album = album1, Position = 1 });
db.AlbumTracks.Add(new AlbumTrack { Track = tr2, Album = album1, Position = 2 });
db.AlbumTracks.Add(new AlbumTrack { Track = tr3, Album = album1, Position = 3 });
db.AlbumTracks.Add(new AlbumTrack { Track = tr4, Album = album1, Position = 4 });
db.AlbumTracks.Add(new AlbumTrack { Track = tr5, Album = album1, Position = 5 });

db.SaveChanges();
```

(or you can just 'add' albumtracks, the rest will go in).

**Note:** You don't need the composite key any more - as your AlbumTrack is basically dependent on the track alone - i.e. you have `only one record` for each track - with 'an album' to attach to.
Also you don't need the `// public int AlbumTrackId { get; set; }` as that's the opposite side, fk is on the albumtrack. And that was wrong in the old setup as well (as you'd need 'two keys' for the fk -  to join table).

And, to add, this whole structure 'suggests' basically that you're simply 'splitting' the Track table  - into two one-to-one tables - and that you could also go with just Track/Album. But that has its own advantages - while you have extra joins and read/writes (on the downside) you get some of the flexibility - or e.g. later you could associate them via normal join table and so on.

Comment: Thanks @NSGaga, a very thorough answer which explained it very well!

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer but I don't understand why you need an intermediate table for the position. Why not just do:

```
public class Track
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
}

public class Album
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Good point about incorporating Position in the Tracks entity. I was reverting from a many to many model where a track *could* be on multiple albums and trying to see if I could get this to work. Is this such an unlikely situation?

Comment: sure the "many-to-many" approach makes sense for "greatest hits" type of albums. I just answered the question based on the OP criteria where a track was limited to one album